# vararg and extension function in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, variadic-functions, extension-function

I am trying to write extension function in kotlin. I came almost to the end but one simple thing stopped me. Code goes like this:

```
fun Bundle.applyWithUserParameters(vararg functionList: () -> Unit = null): Bundle = Bundle().apply {
for (method in functionList)
    method()
FirebaseAnalyticsHelper.clientRepository.getClientData()?.clientID?.let {
    putInt(
        FirebaseAnalyticsHelper.KEY_USER_ID, it
    )
}
}
```

null is underlined and it says: "Null can not be a value of a non-null type Array<out () -> Unit>"

Is there any way to fix this or I am unable to use vararg at all in this case?
Thanks

Comment: You seem to be setting the default value of the varargs parameter to null. That doesn't make much sense. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because in some cases I will send 2,3,4 functions as arguments and in some cases, I will send zero arguments to applyWithUserParameters

Comment: So...? Why does that mean you need `= null`? A vararg, by itself, without a default value, can take 0 or more arguments. How about removing `= null`?

Comment: Can you please write that down, how would it look?
bundle. applyWithUserParameters....?

Comment: How would _what_ look?

Comment: When I call this extension function from my code with zero arguments (in some other class).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237630/discussion-between-sweeper-and-kratos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be trying to set the default value of the varargs parameter to null. This is not needed. Varargs can take 0 parameters, even without a default value.

```
fun Bundle.applyWithUserParameters(vararg functionList: () -> Unit): Bundle = 
    Bundle().apply {
        for (method in functionList)
            method()
        FirebaseAnalyticsHelper.clientRepository.getClientData()?.clientID?.let {
            putInt(
                FirebaseAnalyticsHelper.KEY_USER_ID, it
            )
       }
    }
```

This works:

```
someBundle.applyWithUserParameters()
```

Comment: True that! I didn't know the fact that vararg takes 0 parameters even without default value when you write it with empty brackets. Thanks for your help